# Generating 4 results from IF and AND

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to combine some IF statements that give me effectively 4 results, I will just use A1, B1 etc for ease

In A1 I enter a date
In E1 I have the formula =IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1+21) this generates an expected completion date in that cell

In F1, I would put a actual completion date manually

What I want it to do is generate the following in G1
e.g. E1 has 04/05/15 and a blank in F1, I want this to give me OVERDUE in H1

E1 has 04/05/15 and a date 03/05/15 in F1, I want this to give me CLOSED in H1

E1 has 04/05/15 and a date 05/05/15 in F1, I want this to give me CLOSED OVERDUE in H1

E1 has 27/05/15 and blank in F1, I want this to give me OPEN in H1

I can get the first two by using the formula (for some reason the whole formula doesnt come up on here) =IF(AND(ISBLANK(F1),F1

W1 is a cell that generates a date using the TODAY function

I'm stuck on the other two lines and how to combine it into one formula, I've tried various ways, but mostly I get "too many arguments"

This may make it clearer as I havent got a high enough rep to post an image

Data manually entered into "Date Informed"

I2 04/04/15

I3 04//4/15

I4 04/04/15

I5 04/05/15

Formula generates "expected completion date"

M2 =IF(ISBLANK(I2),"",I2+21)

M3 =IF(ISBLANK(I2),"",I2+21)

M4 =IF(ISBLANK(I2),"",I2+21)

M5 =IF(ISBLANK(I2),"",I2+21)

Data manually entered into "Actual completion date"

N2 None

N3 28/04/15

N4 23/04/15

N5 Blank

Results required in "Status"

P2 OVERDUE

P3 OVERDUE AND CLOSED

P4 CLOSED

P5 OPEN

Comment: give us a dummy data set or a screenshot of it, proper example, seeing a data set table is easier than reading your explanations. provide the expected results column.

Comment: Cant post an image yet as I havent made enough posts

Comment: How does today's date come into play? Is that how you identify `OPEN` vs. `OVERDUE`?

Comment: @Shadowfax put the link to the image in the comments and we will upload it for you in your question. otherwise it is getting complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said I think this may help

```
Col A      Col E       F           G
04/04/15   25/04/15                OVERDUE
04/04/15   25/04/15    28/04/15    OVERDUE AND CLOSED
04/04/15   25/04/15    23/04/15    CLOSED
04/04/15   25/04/15                OPEN
```

In cell `G1` I have the following formula that you need to drag down:

```
=IF(AND(E1<TODAY(),ISBLANK(F1)),"OVERDUE",IF(AND(E1>=TODAY(),ISBLANK(F1)),"OPEN",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(F1),F1>E1),"OVERDUE AND CLOSED","CLOSED")))
```

In words (as per the IF statements):

1. If the expected completion date is in the past and no completion date given then it is `overdue`
2. If the expected completion date is in the future and no completion date given then it is `open`
3. If the actual completion date was later than the expected completion date then `overdue and closed`
4. If the actual completion date was earlier than the expected completion date then `closed`

Comment: YEEEEESSSSS!! Thank you so much

Comment: I never knew Excel formulas could bring so much joy! Do please accept the answer so other users facing similar issues know the solution works.

Comment: And the good thing is that I understand it and could use it to expand some other issues